# When to use slice instead of an array in GO

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I am learning GO. According to documentation, slices are richer than arrays.

However, I am failing to grasp hypothetical use cases for slices.

What would be use case where one would use a slice instead of array?

Thanks!

Comment: A Go array always has a fixed size. If you always need 10 things of type T, `[10]T` is fine. What if you need a variable number of things `n`, where `n` is determined at runtime?

Comment: Please add this as an answer and I will mark as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really pretty elementary and probably should already have been covered in whatever documentation you're reading (unless it's just the language spec), but:  A Go array always has a fixed size. If you always need 10 things of type T, `[10]T` is fine.  But what if you need a variable number of things *n*, where *n* is determined at runtime?

A Go slice—which consists of two parts, a *slice header* and an underlying *backing array*—is pretty ideal for holding information needed to access a variable-sized array.  Note that just declaring a slice-header variable:

```
var x []T
```

doesn't actually allocate any *array* of `T` yet: the slice header will be initialized to hold `nil` (converted to the right type) as the (missing) backing array, 0 as the current size, and 0 as the capacity of this array.  As a result of this, the test `x == nil` will say that yes, x is nil.  To get an actual array, you will need either:

- an actual array, or
- a call to `make`, or
- use of the built-in `append` or similar (e.g., `copy`, `append` hidden behind some function, etc).

Since the call to `make` happens at runtime, it can make an array of whatever size is needed at this point.  A series of calls to `append` can build up an array.  Note that each call to `append` *may* have to allocate a *new* backing array, or *may* be able to extend the existing array in-place, depending on what's in the capacity.  That's why you need `x = append(x, elem)` or `x = append(x, elems...)` and not just `append(x, elem)` or `append(x, elems...)`.

The [Go blog entry on slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) has a lot more to say on this.  I like this page more than the sequence of pages in the [Go Tour starting here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/13), but opinions vary.